# Undefined provider Window in XHRBackend Extension

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I've got my appModule which looks more or less like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ],
  providers: [
    WINDOW_PROVIDER,
    { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: AuthenticationConnectionBackend },
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In where WINDOW_PROVIDER looks like this:

```
import { ValueProvider } from '@angular/core';

export const WINDOW_PROVIDER: ValueProvider = {
  provide: 'Window',
  useValue: window
};
```

And finally AuthenticationConnectionBackend is this one:

```
export class AuthenticationConnectionBackend extends XHRBackend {

  private window;

  constructor(_browserXhr: BrowserXhr, _baseResponseOptions: ResponseOptions,
      _xsrfStrategy: XSRFStrategy, @Inject('Window') injectedWindow: Window) {
    super(_browserXhr, _baseResponseOptions, _xsrfStrategy);

    // injectedWindow = undefined;
    this.window = injectedWindow;
  }
}
```

The problem is that once angular runs the AuthenticationConnectionBackend constructor, the **injectedWindow** value is **undefined** and I need to assign it to a certain variable of the service in order to test the class.

Thanks! If you need some extra information do not hesitate in asking for!